# Partition alignment when imaging with dd

Tags: linux, debian, partition, ssd

I'm running Debian 7 (Wheezy) on my notebook and want to update to Jessie.
When installing, I took care of the partition alignment on the ssd.
My next steps would be to

1. clone the existing SSD to a normal hdd (using `dd`)
2. update the system

In case step 2 fails, I'd like to restore the image from the HDD to the SSD (again, using `dd`).

Would this restore keep the partition alignment intact, i.e. would the SSD be identical (bitwise) before and after the restore?

Comment: yes, as long as you did the full disk (/dev/sda), it is a full binary image. if you are not entirely comfortable with the situation you can mount the disk image and stroll around just to make sure things are there.

Comment: I'm confident that all the data would be present, but I'm wondering about the alignment...

Comment: You can also be confident the alignment will be there. Which sector is it aligned to?

Comment: I would recommend downloading the Clonezilla ISO image and creating a bootable CD or USB stick, and using Clonezilla to backup your disk.  http://clonezilla.org/ - and if you have a server on your network, you can even use PXE and/or tftp to set up a network-bootable Clonezilla (and optionally use NFS or Samba based storage for backup images).

Comment: Does `clonezilla` behave different than `dd` regarding partition alignment when restoring?

Comment: No it does not, it will still be a clone. Ideally you would create an aligned partition of equal size and use dd to clone the partition rather than the disk.